# Animate element based on scroll position inside absolute div with overflow: scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to animate an element based on the scroll position inside a div with the properties `position: absolute` and `overflow: scroll`. The code I've got to so far is basing the animation based on the position on the page position, and changing the opacity. I want to change the property `filter: blur(value);` Below is the code (opacity, not div based scroll) as it exists now:

```
  var header = $('div.modal-container figure.still');
  var range = 200;

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
      height = header.outerHeight(),
      offset = height / 2,
      calc = 1 - (scrollTop - offset + range) / range;

    header.css({
      'opacity': calc
    });

    if (calc > '1') {
      header.css({
        'opacity': 1
      });
    } else if (calc < '0') {
      header.css({
        'opacity': 0
      });
    }

  });
```

Any help on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have in `calc` variable radius of blur in pixels, try something like this:

```
header.css({
  'filter': `blur(${calc}px)`
});

if (calc < 0) {
  header.css({
    'filter': 'none'
  });
}
```

Comment: This works great for blur, but it doesn't account for the scroll position for the absolute div with scrolling overflow.